# initialize a typedef struct variable in CPP

Tags: c++, struct, header-files

I'm trying to access a 3rd party library in which one of the header contains a struct as follows

```
#if defined(V1) || defined(V3)
typedef struct
{
   int8         ErrorCode;
   boolean      isValid;
} validation, *validation_p;
#endif // #ifdef V1/V3
```

So if i would like to access validation/validation_p how can I access within my cpp, It's very clear that we need to define V1/V3 but where and how do I define those??

Sorry for the basic question on CPP

Comment: Before you import that header, obviously.

Comment: ... by saying `#define V1` or `#define V3` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a macro in the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), use the syntax `#define MACRO VALUE`, or, for an empty flag macro, just `#define MACRO`. So, in your case, your code should like like:

```
#define V3 // or V1
#include <thirdpartylib>
```